# Understanding How to Add A JButton to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I am trying to implement some buttons in my JTable. I have been looking at 
[this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm).

What I don't understand is this constructor:

```
public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
}
```

What does the JCheckBox have to do with anything? There is no JCheckBox displayed anywhere nor does it seem it is even relevant to the example. TIA.

Comment: You'll want to wait to see if SO member camickr sees your question since the blog and code are his. I will add the Swing tag to your question to help increase the chances of this happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DefaultCellEditor` usage here is more of a hack for using Buttons as it accepts only `JCheckBox`, `JComboBox` and `JTextField`.

If you really want to implement for `JButton`, you can also do like,

```
class ButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor 
 implements javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor, 
            javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor
```

Else you can update your implementation for using a constructor with `JButton` as parameter or default constructor,

**Approach 1**

```
public ButtonEditor() {
    super(new JCheckBox());
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }
```

and can be accessed as,

```
table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(
        new ButtonEditor());
```

**Approach 2**

```
public ButtonEditor(JButton button) {
    super(new JCheckBox());
    this.button = button;
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }
```

This approach provides better clarity and usage of button component outside the cell editor too,

```
JButton button=new JButton();
table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(
       new ButtonEditor(button));
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble implementing approach 2. My IDE tells me that for 'super(new JCheckBox())' the constructor Object(JCheckBox) is undefined. Also 'fireEditingStopped()' is undefined for type new actionListener. It is not clear from the docs what this really does or why it is necessary.

Comment: Can we discuss in chat? [link to connect](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162815/understanding-how-to-add-a-jbutton-to-a-jtable)

Answer (score 1):

It is because `class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor`, and constructor of `DefaultCellEditor` in your example looks like this `DefaultCellEditor​(JCheckBox checkBox)`